# Listview row text alignment is off on device

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got a listrow in a listview. In Android Studio the preview is showing the desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

However on the device the text alignment is off:

[image: Actual device screenshot]

The layout for the listrow is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_field_lv"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/apptheme_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="01"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/month_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:translationY="-7dp"
            android:text="JUL"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_field_lv"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moment_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Lorum Ipsum"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/sub_text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Placeholder"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is causing the misalignment on the actual device?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_field_lv"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="01"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/month_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="JUL"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:translationY="-7dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_field_lv"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moment_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Lorum Ipsum"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type_lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Placeholder"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, no difference at all.